Manga (probably isekai) about protagonist finding a girl with white hair as bad omen in a demi-human village
I remember one part from that manga, basically the protagonist went to a demi-human village. I can't remember the reason, but I think it's something about trading.
People were half-human, half-animals in this village, cats I think, and they never had white hair. In the village, the protagonist finds a girl that is said to be a bad sign, kind of cursed since she had the white hair I mentioned before.
The protagonist decided to investigate. Turns out that girl is not cursed at all, just really unlucky since her parents died, and she was born with white hair. After the protagonist finds out about what happened to that girl, he hugged her.

Asking guy here, i forgot to mention but after protagonist finds out about what happened to that girl, he hughed her. Small detail, but it might help you

I presume you mean that he hugged her.

Yes, sorry for my mistakes

It's Sudden, But I Came To Another World! But I Hope To Live Safely
chapter 11

(the winning search query: manga albino girl isekai site:www.reddit.com )

That's the one! Thank you, you saved me a lot of trouble
